# Forward nginx to Apache Tomcat Endless Loop

Tags: nginx, tomcat, subdomain, forwarding

I'm totally new to nginx.

I want to forward two subdomains to the two applications in my apache tomcat server.

As I searched over internet, I found that rewrite does the forwarding but I cannot see forwarding. As I see from the logs, it gets into an infinite loop.

Here is my server configuration

```
http {
     upstream tomcat {
       server tomcat.ip.address:8080;
      }
      server {
        listen 80;
        server_name  sub1.domain.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass    http://tomcat/app1
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_redirect http://tomcat/app1 http://sub1.domain.com;
            proxy_buffering off;
            proxy_store     off;

        }
      }
      server {
        listen 80;
        server_name  sub2.domain.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass    http://tomcat/demo;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_redirect http://tomcat/demo http://sub2.domain.com;
            proxy_buffering off;
            proxy_store     off;
        }
      }
}
```

Whenever I invoke sub1.domain.com or sub2.domain.com, I'm get the message that there is a redirection loop problem and it's invalid?

So, How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Here is right way to do it. Hope it would be helpful:

https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSPACE/NginX+Tomcat+Proxying

Comment: it's not exactly what I want. But I tried it, still it doesn't work for me. I'm using tomcat 7 and nginx 1.2.4 stable.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try this:

```
http{
  upstream tomcat {
    tomcat.ip:8080;
  }
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  subdomain1.domain.com;
    location / {
      proxy_pass    http://tomcat/app1;
    }
  }
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  subdomain2.domain.com;
    location / {
      proxy_pass    http://tomcat/app2;
    }
  }
  ....
```

Look at [nginx doc](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUpstreamModule).

Comment: I've tried this @undx. it still shows the welcome screen. Can you let me know if it works for you?

Comment: stupid question but did you restart nginx ? And another question : What the nginx logs are saying ?

Comment: I've restarted it. I added the server keyword before tomcat.ip:8080. problem is whenever I invoke subdomain1.domain.com , it says that the forwarding is invalid